# How to algebraically expand a mathematical operation String

Tags: java, arrays, math, arraylist

Lets say I have

```
String equation = "-2(3u-x)-v"
```

from user input

I want to know if there is a library that would convert this into:
-6u+2x-v

I can't seem to find any thus I have tackled this on my own but it seems a lot of work and I am doing it inefficiently (I only account for u, x, and v).

Below I am modifying the the list to group integers for easier multiplication.

```
char[] charArray = equation.toCharArray();
ArrayList<String> eq= new ArrayList<String>();


    for (int i = 0; i <= charArray.length-1; i++) {
        if (charArray[i] == 'x' || charArray[i] == 'u' || charArray[i] == 'v') {
            eq.add(String.valueOf(charArray[i]));
        }
        else if (charArray[i] == '-' || charArray[i] == '+') {
            int x = 1;
            if (charArray[i+1] != 'u' && charArray[i+1] != 'v' && charArray[i+1] != 'x')
                x = charArray[i+1]-48;
            if (charArray[i] == '-')
                x = x*-1;
            eq.add(String.valueOf(x));
        }
        else if (charArray[i] == '(' || charArray[i] == ')' || charArray[i] == '=') {
            eq.add(String.valueOf(charArray[i]));
        }
    }
```

PS I am new to programming so it might not look professional, sorry about that

Comment: This is a bit vague. Your title suggests you want to just remove parentheses, but actually you're doing an algebraic evaluation. But you haven't said to what extent you want to do such evaluation. Are you wanting to get rid of any sets of parentheses, even layers of them? So really, your converting any algebraic expression involving +, -, or * to something like a "disjunctive normal form" where * is your "conjunction* and +/- is your "disjunction"? What's the extent of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Agreed, the extent to what you want to do is crucial to our answering such a question. It seems you may be looking for a way to parse a string based on mathematical axioms. There is http://javaluator.sourceforge.net/en/home/ . I have never used it, but seems like it may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Well I checked out a couple of libraries but they seem to want me to declare a variable value or I just could not find the methods (exp4j and JEP).I just need to get rid of parentheses to get a simple algebraic form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [Symja library](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) you can expand expressions like this:

```
package org.matheclipse.core.examples;

import static org.matheclipse.core.expression.F.*;

import org.matheclipse.core.eval.ExprEvaluator;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IAST;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.SyntaxError;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.math.MathException;

public class SO_ExpandExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExprEvaluator util = new ExprEvaluator(false, 100);

            // expand an expression by using Expand() or ExpandAll() function
            IExpr result = util.evaluate("ExpandAll(-2(3u-x)-v)");
            // print: -6*u-v+2*x
            System.out.println(result.toString());

            // Show an expression in the Java form:
            String javaForm = util.toJavaForm("ExpandAll(-2(3u-x)-v)");
            // prints: ExpandAll(Plus(Times(CN2,Plus(Times(C3,u),Negate(x))),Negate(v)))
            System.out.println(javaForm.toString());

            // use the JavaForm:
            IAST function = ExpandAll(Plus(Times(CN2, Plus(Times(C3, u), Negate(x))), Negate(v)));
            result = util.evaluate(function);
            // print: -6*u-v+2*x
            System.out.println(result.toString());

        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            // catch Symja parser errors here
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MathException me) {
            // catch Symja math errors here
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this makes my life so easy. Also can you tell me how did you find out about this library?